# Copy part of a UV sphere to rounded surface

Tags: vertices, geometry

I have a project with a UV sphere and I would like to copy only part of the sphere to a rounded surface:

[image: Sphereto Surface]

I have selected the vertices of the surface that interests me but I can't seem to find what is the next step to copy the selected surface to another project (if I do a simple Ctrl-C Ctrl-V then I copy the whole sphere).

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Anthony

Comment: it's not that clear what you mean by "another project"... is it another .blend file?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, sorry if it was unclear,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method could be:

In Edit mode, with those faces selected, use **SHFT + D** to copy the faces followed by **P**  to separate the copy into a new mesh object.

Now you can edit the new object ( or copy and paste to a new scene ).